# How do I execute a function in a parent file, from a child file?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import, tkinter-button

I have a file that contains a class definition. This class definition stores Tkinter `Button` objects, and when these buttons are pressed, I need them to run a function in main.py. My file structure is as follows:

```
 - main.py
 - Classes (Folder)
     - class.py
     - another_class.py
```

`class.py` contains a class with a method `render`, which creates and shows the button, saving it to an attribute `button`:

```python
    def Render(self):
        self.__scrnPos = self.GetScrnPos()

        if self.tile == None:
            txt    = self.multiplier
        else:
            txt    = self.tile.GetLetter() + str(self.tile.GetValue())
        self.colour = self.__GetColour()

        button = tk.Button(
            text    = txt,
            font    = self.font,
            command = lambda: test(),
            bg      = self.colour).place(
            x       = self.__scrnPos[0],
            y       = self.__scrnPos[1],
            width   = self.__size,
            height  = self.__size)

        return button
```

When the button is pressed, it should run the subroutine `test` in `main.py`.

Comment: If I have understood what you mean correctly, you want to import a function from the parent directory. right ?

Comment: @Khanzadeh_AH Not quite, I need it to run something in main.py, because there are variables and other things stored there. I might be able to work with that though, is it possible?

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] as currently there is no information how those files are related, for example how and where is the instance of the class defined in `class.py`  created?

Comment: @acw1668 `class.py` just contains a class definition, nothing else, I'm trying to keep my code organised by keeping things in separate files so I don't have to scroll through thousands of lines of code later on.

Comment: @Lordimass I am asking how and where the class is created.  Without a [mre], it is hard to identify the issue.

Comment: @acw1668 The class is created in class.py, I'm not sure what else to tell you. Literally the only thing in the file *is* the class definition. My problem has been solved by someone else anyway, thanks anyways.